# Return global variable from threaded python function

Tags: python, multithreading, function

I need to spin off a single thread that will run continously in the background and return a set of 10 numbers/characters to the main program each time they are entered without holding up the main program. FYI - The following code should now work on both MS Windows and Linux.
The following test python 2.7x code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import thread
import time
try:
    from msvcrt import getch  # try to import Windows version
except ImportError:
    def getch():   # define non-Windows version
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
char = None
def keypress():
    global char
    char = getch()
thread.start_new_thread(keypress, ())
while True:
    if char is not None:
        print "Key pressed is %s" % char
        char = None
    else:
      print "\nNo keys pressed, continue program is running\n"
      time.sleep(2)
    global char
    char = getch()
```

But when I break it into two sections, main.py and functions.py it seems that the global variable is not being returned:

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# main
from functions import *
import thread
import time
thread.start_new_thread(keypress, ())
while True:
    if char is not None:
        print "Key pressed is %s" % char
        break
        # char = None
    else:
      print "\nNo keys pressed, continue program is running\n"
      time.sleep(1)
```

functions.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#functions.py
char = None
try:
    from msvcrt import getch  # try to import Windows version
except ImportError:
    def getch():   # define non-Windows version
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
def keypress():
    global char
    char = getch()
```

I believe the problem is that the global variable char is not being return to the main program via the thread that accesses the keypress function.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: You might be able to see the problem if you remove everything not absolutely necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, that is what this is. My full code is much larger and wasn't working, so I broke it down to this minimum set.

Comment: You really believe you can't remove the termios calls and all that? How about the output? Have you tried removing the thread start and replacing it with a plain function call? Also, "it seems that" with some interpretation is not a good description, rather report your observations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my split main and functions were not working is because I didn't declare that char was global in main before calling the functions. The corrected code is below and works for me:

main

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# main
from functions import *
import thread
import time
global char  # must be declared as global before any functions that access it
char = None
thread.start_new_thread(keypress, ())
while True:
    global char
    if char is not None:
        print "Key pressed is %s" % char
        char = None
    else:
      print "\nNo keys pressed, continue program is running\n"
      time.sleep(2)
    char = getch()
```

functions

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#functions.py
char = None
try:
    from msvcrt import getch  # try to import Windows version
except ImportError:
    def getch():   # define non-Windows version
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
def keypress():
    global char
    char = getch()
```